# Weblient Flux block for subscribe

Tags: java, spring-webflux, webclient, block, flux

*** I am sure there are better ways of doing this, but I am starting new on webflux, and still iearning***

I have a requirement where I need to make asynchronous calls to different web services fro one service( It is same end point with differet queryparameters each time, so calling it a different service). There are dynamic number of downstream calls

Service[A] ---> ServiceB[1],ServiceB[2],ServiceB[3],ServiceB[4], etc

Now, when I get the response from each instance of ServiceB[n] , I need to know 'this' response is for which request ( 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 , etc). Reason is tha I need to append thais at the end of request to send as response in specific order. They need to be appended in the same order as they were in the original request. ( so I need to identify which response to its request ). I am geiing a List that has the order in which they were requested.

I have the below code which works *functionally*. I.e. when I make one request to Service-A ( which makes 4 calls to 4 Servcie B calls)

BUT, When there is parallel requests to Service-A, I see the ***Flux.merge(asyncRequestList).collectList().block()*** call does not wait for ALL resposnes and still returns from the method.  So I am missing some responses.

```
 public List<ResultSet> invoke(List<ResultSet> requestPayload) {
    String endpoint = "https://ourserver.hostname.com/our-service/api/v1/context?reference={servicereference}"
    List<ResultSet> responsePayload = requestPayload;
    ArrayList<Mono<String>> asyncRequestList = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
        "Request" is a Pojo with 4 fields
        JsonNode request;
        String reference;
        JsonNode response;
        int order; 
    */
        
    for (Requests req : requestPayload) {
        asyncRequestList.add(
            req.getOrder(),
            webClient.post()
                .uri(new UriTemplate(endpoint).expand(reference))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(req.getRequest()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)));

            // register the callback
         asyncRequestList.get(req.getOrder()).subscribe(s2 -> {
             logger.info("Got response :: Request Id : {}, for Reference{}",
                                req.getRequestId(), req.getReference());
                responsePayload.get(req.getOrder()).setResponse(mapper.mapFromString(s2));
        });
    }

    //wait for all responses
    Flux.merge(asyncRequestList).collectList().block();
    logger.info("Got all responses. ");

    return responsePayload; 
}
```

Can anyone point me in right direction here ?
and what tools can I use to debug this ( any network monitors, etc)

Comment: Do you actually have the 4 payloads when you iterate `for (Requests req : requestPayload) {`? I think you have to chain the `requestPayload.map().....` to the point you reach `Flux.merge`.

Comment: Before any answers, is this a fully reactive application. Or is this a Spring MVC (web) application.

Comment: @Felipe yes, during normal runs (when all responses do come through fine),there are logs for all requests/responses.

Comment: @Toerktumlare This is not a fully Reactive application. This is a chaining of RestTemplate based miroservices.This one microservice in question is in the middle somewhere. It's being built using **webclient** to call it's downstream microservice. Immediate downstream microservice is again a RestTemplate based. 
(I do have an opportunity to make that a fully reactive, but not sure what is the impact)